# Opening method in netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, shortcut

How do you open a method in Netbeans?, Example in Eclipse you use F3 to open or move to a method in that or another class. Which shortcut key do I use?

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way, press the ctrl key and click on the method name with the mouse.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Source: For the most recent version, go to http://netbeans.org/kb/index.html then click on the "Keyboard Shortcut Card" link found on the page. Otherwise, [click here](http://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-72.pdf) for version 7.2.